# How to get map's point cloud from rtab_map

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, 3dslam, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How I get `PointCloud` (`PointCloud2`) of the map from `rtab_map`?
I tried topic `/rtabmap/cloud_map` but it has less resolution than cloud from rtabmapviz (see the screenshot below):

**Image from rtabmapbiz (hirez)**
[image: image description]

**Image from /rtabmap/cloud_map (low res)**
[image: image description]

How can i grub `PointCloud` of the map in high resolution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239760/how-to-get-map%27s-point-cloud-from-rtab_map/) by [markovalexey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27531/markovalexey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

by default the topic `/rtabmap/cloud_map` is voxelized at 5 cm. You can change this by setting `cloud_voxel_size` to `0.01` for `rtabmap` node. You may also want to reduce `cloud_decimation` to `1` (default `4`) if you want even more points. See [rtabmap_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#rtabmap) page for more info.

For convenience, you can use [rtabmap_ros/MapCloud](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#RVIZ_plugins) plugin in RVIZ (with `/rtabmap/mapData` topic) to create the 3D point cloud. You will have directly in RVIZ the voxel/decimation parameters. `MapCloud` rviz plugin is also more efficient than `/rtabmap/cloud_map` if you just want to visualize the 3D map.

If you want to save a point cloud to a file (e.g., *pcd or *.ply), you can do it in rtabmapviz after clicking on pause, then File->Export point clouds... You will even have more options to regenerate the point clouds at the resolution you want.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [markovalexey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27531/markovalexey/) on 2016-07-18**:
Thank you.
I want to process this point cloud via PCL. What is better: `use /rtabmap/cloudmap` or `/rtabmap/mapData` and  convert to `pcl::PointCloud` (and how I can do It)?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-07-18**:
In this case, use `/rtabmap/cloud_map` with the corresponding parameters.